# Why doesn't my recursive longest increasing subsequence function work for large inputs?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I wrote it to work on a single test case at a time.
It either takes too long on online judges or returns wrong answers

Source: The [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/longest-increasing-subsequent/problem) I used to test it on

It works perfectly for small cases:

```
#include <iostream>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <vector>
  int LIS[100000];
  void LS (int *arr , int n)
  {
      if (n == 0)
      {
          LIS[0] = 1;
          return;
      }
      if (LIS[n])
      {
          return;
      }
      int i = 0;
      int max = 0;
      while (i < n)
      {
          if (arr[i] < arr[n])
          {
              LS(arr,i);
              if (LIS[i] + 1 > max)
              {
                  max = 1 + LIS[i];
              }
          }
          ++i;
      }
      LIS[n] = max;

  }
  int main()
  {
      int n;
      std::cin >> n;
      int arr[n];
      for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) std::cin >> arr[i];
      LS(arr,n-1);
      std::sort (LIS , LIS+n);
      std::cout << "\n" << LIS[n-1] << "\n";
  }
```

Comment: `int n;
      std::cin >> n;
      int arr[n];` - is *not* valid standard C++. Standard C++ does not support VLAs (Variable Length Arrays). Some compilers unfortunately support it as an extension, but those extensions can usually be turned off (I'd recommend doing so). What you want here is a `std::vector`.

Comment: Recursion usually is much slower than iteration. In case of tail recursion the compiler can transform it to a iterative function. In your case it's not tail recursion. You could either rewrite your code to tail recursion or write a iterative function. https://dev.to/deciduously/tail-recursion-35nb

Answer (score 1):

You said it works perfectly small cases.. than maybe it is stack overflow..

A function call consume stack memory..

If recursive call depth is too deep, stack memory runs out, and crash..

Comment: But I have tried to memoize it.There wouldn't be memory usage in that case would there?

Comment: @ChiragM every function call gets a stack frame on the stack. This can cause a stack overflow very fast.

Comment: @ChiragM ```main()``` --> ```LS()``` --> ```LS()``` --> .....   Every time you call a function, it use stack memory.. and when you use parameters and local variables, it use stack memory.. Increase stack memory or reduce recursive function call depth.

Answer (score 0):

When you read `int n` value from `std::cin`, you have to dynamically allocate memory for your array `arr`, so you should first declare `int *arr`, then get the user input the same way as you're doing it now, and then allocate memory using `arr = new int[n]`.

When it comes to the long time it takes to compute next values using recursive function, you should think about remaking the function to use tail recursion, which is much closer to iteration. You can check the difference by writing two programs for counting Fibonacci numbers - one recursive and another one iterative, then check how long it takes to compute ~50th value using both methods.